# Obtaining a single value of EGF in terms of multiple OGF evaluations?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I have access to ordinary generating function $f$ which I can evaluate at $d$ arbitrary real-valued points $f(s_1),f(s_2),\ldots,f(s_d)$. I need to know the approximate value of $g(t_1)$, which is the exponential generating function $g$ evaluated at a single point $t_1>0$.

What's a practical way of doing this?

Wikipedia has a [section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function_transformation#Integral_transformations) on obtaining $g$ from $f$ using complex integration, but I think I need some kind of real-valued discrete transform.

Motivation: I need to go from Laplace domain to time domain, have efficient implementation of resolvent, but not a nice closed form.